# Taking in input with spaces using std::getline() in c++

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to coding in c++, and I am using Visual Studio Code on MAC. I have tried to find the right code so that I can enter a string with spaces, but everything that I tried hasn't worked. I tried `std::getline(std::cin, name)`, but when I ran the code, and it came time to input the name, it just showed nothing where the name should have been. I don't know if there is something wrong with Visual Studio Code, or if there is just a little bit of code that I am missing. Here is the code that I am having a problem with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

std::string name;

std::cout << "Please, enter the name of your nation: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
std::cout << "General Williams: " << name << " is a great name!\n";
}
```

Comment: The code you'e shown here should work (though there are several superfluous header includes, they shouldn't matter. I suspect you're having integration issues with VSCode more than anything else. Compile this from a command prompt with clang++, run it from the shell, and it should work.

Comment: Could you maybe explain more, I am pretty new to coding. What do you mean by clang++ and shell?

Comment: The VSCode website would do a far better job of explaining how that IDE works better than I ever could, as would any number of how-to sites covering how to develop c and c++ code projects using VCSode on a variety of platforms (including mac). Regardless, as I said, that code looks acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed your code and it worked.
Maybe you can not see your result because you run with .exe!

please Add "std::getchar()" to end of your code and try it again.

```
int main()
{
        std::string name;

        std::cout << "Please, enter the name of your nation: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        std::cout << "General Williams: " << name << " is a great name!\n";
        std::getchar();

}
```